# Load jquery on click multiple times in flipbook

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this script which loads  when i click on my next button. The problem is that im working on a flipbook and i need multiple of the same content to load on each page i turn on. At the moment all the content loads on all the pages on first click.

i have tried change `.on` to `.one` but that just loads everything once on all pages on first click.

```
$('#bb-nav-next').on('click touchstart', function() {
```

Comment: what is `flipbook` is it a plugin? link it here.

Comment: @pedram Yes it's a plugin, here is link: https://tympanus.net/Development/BookBlock/.